# How to convert Postgres BYTEA format to Ethereum string address (PYTHON)?

Tags: addresses, database

**Bytea** (hex) is format of PSQL. It is used by many explorers/dapps/apps to store ethereum address. how to convert this format to Python String?

By default it is read as a memory view.

More on Bytea: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/datatype-binary.html

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Convert bytes to python bytes format

Step 2 : convert bytes to hex format

Step 3 (optional) : append 0x to the hex format

```
address = bytes(bytea_from_psql)
hex_address = address.hex()
full_address = "0x" + hex_address
```